# How to add inline script to last shortcode on the page?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I use many my custom shortcodes on the page and I would like to add some inline script/layout to last my shortcode on the page.

Example:

```
[my-shortcode]
// <div>my layout</div>
...
[my-shortcode]
// <div>my layout</div>
...
[my-shortcode]
// <div>my layout</div>
// <script>my script</script>
```

Above inline script added only to last my shortcode. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Will it work?? have you tried? what it do? lol..

Comment: @Jayr what do you mean? I came here to ask how can I do it

Comment: After slashes my layout/script inside my shortcode